# Generate equation after a certain amount of time

Tags: android, android-studio, timer

I'm working on a school project in Android Studio and so far I've written a code which generates a random equation and then display this equation in a textview. Here is the code:

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};

            Random random = new Random();
            int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

            List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
                String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
                operations.add(operation);
            }

            int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
            List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
                int number = random.nextInt(10)+1;
                numbers.add(number);
            }

            String equation = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
                equation += numbers.get(i);
                equation += operations.get(i);
            }
            equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() -1);

            TextView TextEquation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextEquation.setText(equation);

            String stringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);

            // Resultat der Rechung berechnen

            double doubleAnswer = eval(stringResultOfEquation);

            String stringAnswer = Double.toString(doubleAnswer);

            TextView textAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            textAnswer.setText(stringAnswer);
```

So far I've tried to use the TimerTask command:

```
TimerTask timerTaskWaiting = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    Timer timerwaiting = new Timer();
    timerwaiting.schedule(timerTaskWaiting, 5000);
```

I've put the "equation generater code" and put it into "public void run(){...}" but the app crashed when I tried it out.

My question now is, if there is a simple way which will generate the equation after a certain amount of time (for example 5 seconds) I mean, I want that the equation will be generated 5 seconds after the app is launched.

If there is anything unclear in my question, feel free to ask and I will try to clarify the problem :)

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to wait for 5 seconds? This seems like you are *trying* to create a poor user experience. I have a feeling there is something else you want to accomplish, and there may be a better way to accomplish it without stalling the application.

Comment: The 5 seconds were just an example, it could be 1 second or 2 seconds as well :D However I've already found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code should suffice for you to understand what you need to do. obviously there are other ways you can achieve this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            generateAndDisplayEquation();
        }
     }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: yeah, I've just found this solution but thanks nevertheless :)

Comment: Then delete your question or accept the answer so that people in the future will know it is it's solution. Glad you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJava library, it is very easy tool to organize periodic tasks.